# What is STOP: 0x0000007B error

Tags: windows, boot, bsod

Sometime, I get this after booting, before entering Windows.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1ODq.jpg]

What does 0xF7BED528 parameter signify? I search Google and find result for [0x0000007B](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103). But I cannot find something for parameter 0xF7BED528. What is this? Why it appears? What is it causing?

Comment: Have you installed any other OS's recently or used somthing that may modify the boot sector (TruCrypt, some DRM systems, ect...)?

Comment: No.. but I do change hard disk and RAM sometime a year ago. I only notice this problem in recent months.

Comment: Thanks for the question. The answer fixed it for me. My issue happened when transitioning a VM from VMWare to VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3):

0xF7BED528 is the first parameter. You get the **0x0000007B STOP code** with the important parameter 2 with 0xc0000034 which means device not found.

```
C:\Users\André>err 0xc0000034
# for hex 0xc0000034 / decimal -1073741772
  STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND                                   ntstatus.h
# Object Name not found.
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x34
# for hex 0x34 / decimal 52
  ERROR_DUP_NAME                                                 winerror.h
# You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on
# the network. If joining a domain, go to System in Control
# Panel to change the computer name and try again. If joining
# a workgroup, choose another workgroup name.
# 2 matches found for "0xc0000034"
```

This is caused when you change the SATA mode from IDE to AHCI without enabling the AHCI driver first.

**Error message occurs after you change the SATA mode of the boot drive**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

Comment: What is the `err` program that you used in your question? That is interesting.

Comment: So 0xF7BED528 means it happens because the SATA mode is changed?

Comment: @AlvinWong this program is part of the Windows 7 SDK.

Comment: @Dipa **no**, again you get the 0x0000007B bugcheck.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still confused... I know about 0x0000007B, but what is  0xF7BED528?

Comment: this is the first parameter which contains the address of a UNICODE_STRING structure, or the address of the device object that could not be mounted.